# Perdida de datos en Consulta SQL server con WordPress

Tags: php, sql-server, wordpress, pdo

sucede que cuando ejecuto la consulta atraves del Motor de `BBDD` me trae **15.402** registros, pero cuando ejecuto la sentencia atraves de la pagina (en `WordPres`) y con protocolo de `PDO` solo me tare **13.615** registro lo cual me deja con una perdida de **1.787** registros.

La verdad ya hice todas las pruebas que se, entre ellas caprure la sentencia que se esta ejecutando en la pagina y la ejecute en el motor de BBDD y es exactamente igual y me trae los 15 mil registros.

Pongo mi código de ejecución...

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT CONTACT.CONTACTID, CONTACT.EMAIL, FIRSTNAME + ' ' + LASTNAME as NAME, ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT AS ACOUNT 
FROM CONTACT 
    INNER JOIN ACCOUNT on CONTACT.ACCOUNTID = ACCOUNT.ACCOUNTID 
    INNER JOIN ACCOUNTPRODUCT on ACCOUNT.ACCOUNTID = ACCOUNTPRODUCT.ACCOUNTID 
    INNER JOIN PRODUCT on ACCOUNTPRODUCT.PRODUCTID = PRODUCT.PRODUCTID 
    INNER JOIN SIE_ACCOUNT_ADICIONAL on ACCOUNT.ACCOUNTID = SIE_ACCOUNT_ADICIONAL.ACCOUNTID 
    INNER JOIN SIE_ACCOUNT_SOPORTE on ACCOUNT.ACCOUNTID = SIE_ACCOUNT_SOPORTE.ACCOUNTID
WHERE ACCOUNT.TYPE = 'Cliente' 
    AND PRODUCT.ACTUALID LIKE '%1E%' 
    AND ACCOUNT.STATUS = 'Activo' 
    AND ACCOUNTPRODUCT.USERFIELD1 in ('En Soporte', 'Negociando Soporte', 'Implementacion') 
    AND SIE_ACCOUNT_SOPORTE.ESTADO_DEL_CLIENTE_ENTERPR in ('En Soporte', 'Negociando Soporte', 'Implementación') 
    AND ( 
        CONTACT.EMAIL not like '%repetido%' 
        AND CONTACT.EMAIL not like '%noseubica%' 
        AND CONTACT.EMAIL not like '%correorepetido%' 
        AND CONTACT.EMAIL not like '%pendiente%' 
        AND CONTACT.EMAIL not like '%@siesa.com%' 
        AND CONTACT.EMAIL not like '%inactivo%' 
    ) 
    AND UNIDADNEGUNO_E = 'T' 
    AND CODIGO_SUCURSAL_CLIENTE = '001' 
    AND CONTACT.STATUS = 'Activo' 
ORDER BY EMAIL ASC";

    $_SESSION['sql']= $sql;
    $consulta = $conexion->prepare($sql);
    $resultado = $consulta->execute();

    // var_dump($resultado);

    if($consulta->columnCount() > 0){ 
        $_SESSION['data_rows']=array(); 
        $contador=0; 
        foreach($consulta as $row){
            $contador++; 
            $cuerpo.="
                <tr>
                    <td>".utf8_encode($contador)."</td>
                    <td>".utf8_encode($row['CONTACTID'])."</td>
                    <td>".utf8_encode($row['EMAIL'])."</td>
                    <td>".utf8_encode($row['NAME'])."</td>
                    <td>".utf8_encode($row['ACOUNT'])."</td>
                </tr>
            ";
        }

        $tabla='
        <div style="width: 100%">
            <br>
            <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #c3c3c1;"><strong>La consulta arrojo un resultado de '.$contador.' registros </strong></div>
            <br>
            <table style="width: 100%" tabindex="-1" id="datos_tabla" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>POSICION</th>
                        <th>CONTACTID</th>
                        <th>EMAIL</th>
                        <th>NAME</th>
                        <th>ACOUNT</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    '.$cuerpo.'
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>';
    }
    else{
        $tabla=" <div style='width: 100%'>El parametro Buscado no cuenta con datos, por favor intenta de nuevo.<div>";
    }
```

De antemano agradezco la atencion prestada y receptivo a cualquier sugerencia o respuesta.

Comment: Maestro @A.Cedano se que ud sabe mucho de BBDD si puede ayudarme :)

Comment: La misma consulta debe de regresar la misma cantidad de filas sin importar de donde se llama. En el código publicado no se incluye la consulta usada. Hay que verificar que sea la misma usada desde ambas partes.

Comment: @LuisCazares gracias, y si se supone que deberia retornar las mismas filas, pero eso es lo extraño que, imprimi el esql que se estaba ejecutando en la pagina, lo imprimi y lo ejecute en  `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio` y ese mismo sql me arroja mas registros.

Comment: Para poder recibir ayuda, creo que debes compartir como creas tu consulta. El código que publicas es sólo como la muestras en pantalla.

Comment: @LuisCazares, he agregado la consulta que se esta generando desde la pagina, espero puedas detectar si hay algún inconveniente

Comment: mi primera duda es que tiene que ver wordpress en todo esto.. parece simplemente php...

Comment: mi segunda duda es.. le estas pegando a la misma base de datos?

Comment: y otra prueba que haria, mas simple todavia, es correr un count desde los dos lados... un simple select count de la tabla

Comment: @gbianchi gracias, si es php que se esta manejando dentro de un plugin de worpress, lo menciono, por que no se si algun proceso interno de el me este interfieriendo con la consulta.

Comment: no deberia, pero si fuera el caso, deberia haber estado escrito en la pregunta no? ;)

Comment: @gbianchi si, se esta ejecutando en la misma base de datos

Comment: probaste los count?

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, en el motor me traer la cantidad, pero en la pagina me trato de imprimer la consulta asi ` $consulta = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        var_dump($consulta);` pero la peticion me devuleve un errro, no se si que sucede

Comment: @srJJ y yo menos... algo mal hiciste, si podias tirar semejante query antes, un count deberia ser trivial

Comment: Si, @gbianchi, la lógica dice eso, pero la realidad es que WordPres maneja los procesos de una forma muy singular, cabe decir que apenas estoy familiarizandome con el CRM, NOTA: a la otra consulta le quite todos los campos y deje solo el count con el email y quite el el order by, pero deje todas la condiciones, pero igual en el motor asi mismo si funciono